# Android EditText with decimal value in format (3,2)

Tags: android, android-edittext, decimalformat

I have search a lot but not found solution to my problem.
How can I have a editText in which user can enter number in decimal format in which format should be a integer before decimal and two integer after decimal.

If user enter 1 then it should be 1.00 and not allow to enter value grater then 9.99.

I have refer different code but nothing is working.
below is my code -

```
 public class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter {

    Pattern mPattern;

    public DecimalDigitsInputFilter(int digitsBeforeZero,int digitsAfterZero) {
        mPattern=Pattern.compile("[0-9]{0," + (digitsBeforeZero-1) + "}+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero-1) + "})?)||(\\.)?");
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            Matcher matcher=mPattern.matcher(dest);       
            if(!matcher.matches())
                return "";
            return null;
        }

    }
```

and

```
mSetupProfileViewHolder.mAthleteGPAET.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(3,2)});
```

but it allow user to input value all inter like 333,999 etc.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use a `TextWatcher` and then check what the user has typed before they submit it. Here is an example of the code you want to implement:

```
final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {             

   }

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,int arg2, int arg3) {             

   }

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
       if (arg0.length() > 0) {
           String str = et.getText().toString();
           et.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
               public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                       count--;
                       InputFilter[] fArray = new InputFilter[1];
                       fArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(100);
                       et.setFilters(fArray);
                       //change the edittext's maximum length to 100. 
                       //If we didn't change this the edittext's maximum length will
                       //be number of digits we previously entered.
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            char t = str.charAt(arg0.length() - 1);
            if (t == '.') {
                count = 0;
            }
            if (count >= 0) {
                if (count == 2) {                        
                    InputFilter[] fArray = new InputFilter[1];
                    fArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(arg0.length());
                    et.setFilters(fArray);
                    //prevent the edittext from accessing digits 
                    //by setting maximum length as total number of digits we typed till now.
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The above code will not allow the user to enter more than two digits after the decimal point and you can also enter any number of digits before the decimal point. Hope this helps, let me know if you have any issues!